# How to add px value to rem value in CSS using SASS variables?

Tags: css, sass

```
add($input-line-height * 1em, add($input-padding-y * 2, $input-height-border, false)) !default;
```

I am using this above to get something like this `height: calc(1.5em + 1.5rem + 2px);`

But instead I get something like this `height: calc(1.5em + 1.5rem2px);`

I am using a postcss optimize plugin on Webpack. My production files never compile due to `1.5rem2px` which gives the following error below:

```
1.5em + 1.5rem2px
---------^
Expecting end of input, "RPAREN", "ADD", "SUB", "MUL", "DIV", got unexpected "UNKNOWN_DIMENSION"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your `add` mixin looks like, but here are some examples that I successfully tested:

```
$height1: $input-line-height * 1em;
$height2: $input-padding-y * 2;

div {
  height: calc(#{$height1} + #{$height2} + #{$input-height-border});
}
```

or

```
div {
  --varA: #{$input-line-height} * 1em;
  --varB: #{$input-padding-y} * 2;
  --varC: calc(var(--varA) + var(--varB) + #{$input-height-border});
  height: var(--varC);
}
```

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/jarkin13/pen/OJMvrGO). Hope this helped!